# Similarity function in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, similarity

I'm new of Lucene. I built an Index composed by 4 fields. In two of this I used NGrams for tokenization but now i need a good similarity function to retrieve documents with a useful score.

In particular i want to implement Jaccard Similarity. There isn't an apposite implementation of this Similarity in Lucene. 
Which are the methods to override to implements this simple function?
Can I extends DefaultSimilarity?

I surf the web but it's difficult to figure out how to create a new similarity.

Thanks all for answer.